# How do I choose a file names with consecutive numeric suffixes?

Tags: bash, files, scripting, osx

I like to preserve things, so I want to preserve `.bash_history`.

I would like to copy it into a directory using a script. Like here

```
#!/bin/bash
#Something here? number=~/Desktop/Coding/Bash\ Histories/bash_history "?"
cp ~/.bash_history ~/Desktop/Coding/Bash\ Histories/bash_history #$number "?"
```

But I already have a file named `bash_history`, `bash_history 2`, `bash_history 3` and so on.

I want it to check for the highest number, in this case 5. And if `bash_history 5` exists then I want it to name it `bash_history 6` instead.

And if it would be `bash_history 11111` then I want it to name it `bash_history 11112`.

I'm not sure which command I should use here, `if` in combination with `grep` or something?

Comment: You may be better off keeping the current (i.e., most recent) file number in a separate file; something like `read num < bash_history_num; num=$((num+1)); cp .bash_history path/bash_history$num; echo "$num" > bash_history_num`. Especially if you're considering having over 10,000 files.

Comment: Check out [logrotate (8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with  `ls`, `sort`, `tail` and `cut`.

Start with renaming `bash_history` to `bash_history 1` so all files have a number.
Then run the following to copy the next file:

```
#!/bin/bash

D=~/Desktop/Coding/Bash\ Histories

num=$(ls "$D" | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort -nr | head -1)
num=$(( num + 1 ))
cp ~/.bash_history "$D/bash_history $num"
```

The `ls $D` just lists the files in the "storage" directory. From each of the names (e.g. `bash_history 16`, that doesn't include the path), the `cut -d ' ' -f 2` splits on `' '` and takes the second field (the number `16`). The numbers found in that way are sorted in reverse (`-r`) as numbers (`-n`), because as strings `10` would be before `2`. From that list (remember it is reversed), you take the first, i.e. the highest number.
That number you increase and use for the next file.

I would prefer to determine an order of magnitude (e.g. 5 digits) first and then use `printf %05d $num` to get leading zeros myself (that keeps the files alphabetically in the same ordering as the numbers (at least until you hit 100000))

Comment: Could you explain more in depth what the command does?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @Anthon `ls` can do all thing by himself `D="~/Desktop/Coding/Bash Histories/bash_history" ; ls -vr1 "$D*" | (read p n ; cp ~/.bash_history "$D $[$n+1]")`

Comment: @Costas Thanks. It looks like it pays to reread `ls` man page after 30 years. I have never seen the -v option before.